# What's the drawback of using Windows 1809 fast sign-in?

Tags: windows-10-v1809

Windows 1809 now allows **fast first sign-in**, i.e., logging on to a PC for the first time looks like this:

[image: fast sign-in]

<sub>(Image source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1809)</sub>

instead of: "Hi... This might take several minutes... etc.".

This feature [needs to be activated with a group policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1809#faster-sign-in-to-a-windows-10-shared-pc). Thus, it must have some drawback---otherwise, it would be enabled by default. What is the drawback?

Comment: The drawback is you'll have to start doing actual work sooner.

Comment: Do you mean apart from what is described in the group policy description - 'Microsoft account users will not see the opt-in prompt for services.'?